# XML To Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to import an xml file into the sql server with no success yet.
The xml file is structured like this:

```
<Users xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
  <User>
    <PartitionKey>be-BY</PartitionKey>
  </User>
</Users>
```

I am using the following code:

```
   SELECT 
    xmldata.value('(PartitionKey)[1]', 'NCHAR(10)') AS 'partition_key'  
FROM 
    (SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
     FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\SkillageXML\userstest1111.xml',
        SINGLE_BLOB
        ) 
        AS T(x)
    )  AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY 
    x.nodes('/Users/User') AS X(xmldata);
```

However, I don't see any value after it is done with processing the file. Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works like a charm for me:

```
SELECT 
    XUsers.value('(PartitionKey)[1]', 'NCHAR(10)') AS 'partition_key'  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        BulkXML = CAST(BulkColumn AS XML)
     FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\SkillageXML\userstest1111.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BX 
    ) AS T
CROSS APPLY 
    BulkXml.nodes('/Users/User') AS XTbl(XUsers);and returns:

partition_key
be-BY
```

I think you're approach of using the  `AS T(x)` alias twice is causing confusion - try to use something more meaningful and not the same alias for both things.

Comment: Use [INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx)